# How to get <p> tag value from XMLHttpRequest response and set in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, string

I am trying to upload file using `XMLHttpRequest` and in case of error, I am getting the whole error `div` in response.
From that `div`, I want the text inside paragraph i.e.(File is empty.Please provide comma seperated taskids.) tag to set in HTML page.
Talking about error code 409 in code.

Request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
var url = '/uiris/actions/'+$("#actionName").val()+'/do?time=' + new Date().getTime()+'&subaction=fileupdate';
xhr.open("POST",url, true);
xhr.send(formdata);
xhr.onload = function(e) {

    if (this.status == 200) {
        refreshView();
    } else {
        if (this.status === 409) {
            $('#action').html(this.responseText);  
        } else if (this.status === 401) {
            window.location = "/xyz/";
        } else if (this.status === 422) {
             alert("Unable to perfom task");
             refreshView();
        } else {
            alert("Unable to connect to application");
        }
        refreshView();
    }
};
```

Response:

```
    <div id="errorDiv" class="margin-top-10-px">
    <h2>Error</h2>
    <p>File is empty.Please provide comma seperated taskids.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And the problem is? Pass it to the jQuery constructor and then `.find()` the `<p>` node...

Comment: It would look like `$(this.responseText).find("p").text()`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply jQuery-ify it and `find` the `text()` you want:

```
$(this.responseText).find("p").text();
```